# Is this pylint warning a bug?

Tags: python, pylint

Three tiny Python 3 files are required:

1. Empty `__init__.py`
2. `main.py` with one line: `config = "data"`
3. `sub.py` with one line: `import main; print(main.config)`

`python3 sub.py` (and also python2) prints the word `data` as expected, but pylint warns when checking `sub.py`:

> E:  1,20: Module 'main' has no 'config' member (no-member)

I have no explanation for it.

Comment: Are these all in the same folder? I'm wondering if there is some sort of absolute import vs relative import mix-up that PyLint is stumbling on.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes, they are in the same folder. No other files are present.

Comment: Do you call PyLint from within that folder or from the parent folder? Does it work one way and not the other?

Comment: @SethMMorton I have tried both ways and there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> pylint doesn't load any C extensions by default, because those can run arbitrary code.

method:
create a new file named `.pylintrc`in your project root dir
and paste this:

```
extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5
```

then it will work.

Reference: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html

[Related Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43907094/2311167)

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question posted here by mistake.